# Session not saving values

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have multiple session variables, which both won't accept any values given to them by other variables. I have tried to debug and have found nothing. Here is the function I am using...

```
    public void logIn(object sender, EventArgs e) //triggers when login button is clicked
    {

        db_connection(); //connects to database using above function

        string emailAddress = email.Text.ToString();
        string passwordR = password.Text.ToString(); //email and password are converted to variables

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct            
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select))
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);

            string sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
            Session["personID"] ="";
            Session["personID"] = sessionVar;

            int sessionVarAddress = Int32.Parse(table.Rows[0]["address_addressID"].ToString());
            Session["address_addressId"] = sessionVarAddress;


            if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                if (Session["personID"] != null) //if the person ID is present do this following statement
                {
                    hideDiv.Visible = false;
                }

                Response.Redirect("myAccount.aspx"); // if user logs in successfully redirect to my account pag

            }

            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx"); //if login fails, home page is returned
            }

            connect.Close();
        }
        }
```

Comment: What you'll get value in `sessionVar` when execute this line - `string sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();` at the debug time ?

Comment: So, how did you debug this?

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel Added break points to see the values that were being retained by the sessions, brought back nothing on both occasions. Have tried to move in and out of the statement with no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What session provider are you using ? In-process, SQL server ? Is the client Cookie enabled ? Have you configured cookie-less mode ? What exact error are you getting when you put a breakpoint on 'Session["personID"] = sessionVar' - does 'sessionVar' have a value ? Are you describing the session being empty on post-back or immediately after being set ? If you put a Debug.WriteLine() of the session variable, does it get output correctly to the debug window ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I get the correct corresponding value which is imported from the table e.g. 3

Comment: @PhillipH session provider? I am in visual studio so i assumed this had all been configured by itself as the session itself is being created and works although the value is not stored. There is no error itself as the program is not broken it's just not doing what I expect it to do, I.e. storing the value from the variable. sessionVar is getting the correct value. How do I check if the client is cookie enabled? Do i need to configure 'cookie-less mode?'

Comment: @Richard1996 - all explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa478952.aspx